# Why return value of mysqli_select_db() is always 1 inthe below code?

Tags: php, mysqli

In the below code even if I am putting the wrong database name then also it is giving database selected?

```
<?php
$servername='localhost';
$username='********';
$password='********';
$conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password);
if($conn->connect_error)
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    else{
           echo "database connected successfully!";
     }
$q1="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS id2081161_medicalvaluetravel";
if(!mysqli_query($conn,$q1))
{
        echo("Error creating database:".mysqli_error($conn));
}
echo $selectdb=mysqli_select_db($conn,"travel");
if(!$selectdb){
    echo("database not selected!");
}
    else{
            echo ("database selected!".$selectdb);
    }
?>
```

output :
database connected Successfully!1database selected!1

Answer (score -1):

MySQLi_select_db is a function used to change the default database for the connection.

So when it return `1` that's mean that the connection to that specific database is successful.

If it is `0` that means no connections was established.

So true(1) on success and false(0) on failure.

If you want to change it use IF:

```
if($selectdb == 1)
{
    //Do something or change $selectedDb into other value;
}
else
{
    //Do something else
}
```

Comment: Please, please. For the sake of yourself and everybody. Do not use w3fools as a point of reference

Comment: Done @DarylGill fixed it. But for the simplicity I did that. But can I know why  you hate w3schools ?

Comment: W3schools is an unreliable source of information. Whilst yes, some points are valid. Some of the examples provided are insecure, vulnerable/improperly formatted leaving your application at risk

Comment: ^^ agreed w3schools is good, for about 3% but it teaches bad practice, unsafe code and if you view-source of the site.. it's ... terrible

Comment: Sir why it is giving return value 1 even if the database I am selecting doesn't exist? This is my question.

Comment: I think because it is taking then the default database